# Qsqlrelationaldelegate with qsqlrelationaltablemodel for one record

Tags: c++, qt

QSQlrelationAldelegate is used with qsqlrelationaltablemodel, an example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlrelationaldelegate.html).

I need to change the record in a new window. There will be only one entry, but with external keys.

How in this case use qsqlrelationaldelegate? What will be the request?

I use Qt 6.2.1

Any help, please.

Comment: what do you mean by "I need to create a window change wwindow."?

Comment: I need to change the record in a new window.